# Latitude and longitude become 0 when location is off in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

I am getting location like this

```
BasicGeoposition myLocation = new BasicGeoposition();
        if(cachedLocation != null)
        {
            ApplicationDataCompositeValue cachedPostion = (ApplicationDataCompositeValue)cachedLocation;
            myLocation.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(cachedPostion[latKey]);
            myLocation.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(cachedPostion[longKey]);
        }
        else
        {
            Geoposition position = await GetGeoPosition();
             //rest of the code
        }
```

}

Here, `myLocation.Latitude` and myLocation.Longitude become 0 when the device location is off. I want to make an array with `myLocation` and some other user data. But if the location is 0 I should not add it into the array. Instead of checking every places whether this is 0 or not is there any single way to assign it as null if the location is off. Simply how to check whether the location is off or not?
Please help me.

**UPDATE**

in another class

```
BasicGeoposition currentLocation = await MetrixLocationAssistant.GetCurrentLocation();

string currentLatitude = MetrixFloatHelper.ConvertNumericFromNumberToDB(Convert.ToDecimal(currentLocation.Latitude));
string currentLongitude = MetrixFloatHelper.ConvertNumericFromNumberToDB(Convert.ToDecimal(currentLocation.Longitude));
personData.DataFields.Add(new DataField("geocode_lat", currentLatitude));
personData.DataFields.Add(new DataField("geocode_long", currentLongitude));
```

Comment: @mjwills please check the UPDATE  part

Comment: if its 0 I should not add. Because when the location is off it returns 0 for those values.

Comment: Perfect. So do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation for the Geolocator class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator), you can retrieve the access status for the geo service, something like this:

```
var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
switch (accessStatus)
{
    case GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed:
        break;

    case GeolocationAccessStatus.Denied:
        break;

    case GeolocationAccessStatus.Unspecified:
        break;
}
```

But checking a couple of coordinates for zero is not very expensive. Unless your app is about navigation south of Africa in the Atlantic ocean, treating the (0,0) coordinate specially is unlikely to cause trouble.